# Entity Framework and DataNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagrid

Has anyone managed to bind a DataNavigator and a DataGrid using the DataSource property and the ADO.NET Entity Framework so that add and delete (+ and - buttons in the data navigator). work? I have the problem, that everytime i click on the add button of the DataNavigator, the EntityState is always set to detached. I can't figure out, how to add this detached entity to the DataContext.

my code is simple (using a static session class and a partial class):

```
internal class Session
{
    private static Entities _entities;

    public static Entities Entities
    {
        get { return _entities ?? (_entities = new Entities()); }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitData();
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        gridControl1.DataSource = Session.Entities.SomeObjects;
        dataNavigator1.DataSource = Session.Entities.SomeObjects;
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class SomeObjects
{
    public SomeObjects()
    {
        PropertyChanged += SomeObject_PropertyChanged;
        ObjectId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    private void SomeObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
            Debug.WriteLine(EntityState); // when i change a existing record in the grid, EntityState is set to modified and can be saved easily using SaveChanges. But when i add a new entity, EntityState is always set to detached.
    }
}
```

Help's appreciated!

-christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `BindingSource` control instead of using `DataSource` and handle `AddingNew` event to manually set State to `Added` by calling `AddObject`.

DataGrid doesn't know anything about source of data so it cannot communicate with entity framework context / set and add object. You must do it manually and for that you need some event to handle when new record is added. I believe `AddingNew` and `BindingSource` is way to go.